# Cover art size from a MP3 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'am trying to write a script that gives me the dimension of the Cover art in a mp3 file, the furthest I've is via Mutgen doing:

```
audiofile = mutagen.File(wavefile, easy=False)
print(audiofile.tags)
```

but then from that raw output how can I extract the dimensions like 400x400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [stagger](https://pypi.org/project/stagger/) and [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/), i.e.:

```
import stagger, io, traceback
from PIL import Image

try:
    mp3 = stagger.read_tag('Menuetto.mp3')
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(mp3[stagger.id3.APIC][0].data))
    print(im.size)
    # (300, 300)
    # im.save("cover.jpg") # save cover to file
except:
    pass
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Didn't know that seeing (600, 600) could make a grown man so happy, thanks alot for your help this have been a real head scratcher of mine for awhile :)